# Vue Bootstrap - Hide first Modal when the second modal is open

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this button :

```
<b-button variant="success" v-b-modal.import-list-type>
    <feather-icon
        icon="DownloadCloudIcon"
        class="mr-50"
    />
    <span class="align-middle">Import</span>
</b-button>
```

When this button is click It's showing a modal with this code:

```
<b-modal
    id="import-list-type"
    cancel-variant="secondary"
    hide-footer
    centered
    size="lg"
    title="Select Import Type"
>
    <ProjectImportType/>
</b-modal>
```

On this modal you can see I called child component called : `<ProjectImportType/>`

On this child component I have a button like this :

```
<b-button variant="primary" v-b-modal.import-xml-modal> Import XML </b-button>
```

When this button is click it's showing another modal with this code :

```
<b-modal
    id="import-xml-modal"
    cancel-variant="secondary"
    hide-footer
    centered
    size="xl"
    title="New Import"
    @shown="handleImportTypeModal"
>
    <template #modal-header="">
        <b-img
            :src="require('@/assets/images/projects/xml.png')"
            width="34"
            alt="New Import"
        />
        <h5 class="mr-auto ml-2 mt-2" vertical-align="bottom">New Import</h5>
    </template>
    <ProjectImportNew/>
</b-modal>
```

Now, When this second modal is showing I want to hide the first modal.
Could you please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

On the first modal, you can add a v-if="showImportTypeModal" directive, and set it to false when you click the second button. showImportTypeModal would be a data property being false by default and setted true when you click the first button.

Comment: then the second modal is hiding too as it's child of first modal :(

Comment: they should be siblings, not parent and child